# From hex to ascii in python

Tags: python, hex, ascii, python-2.x, xor

Hey all i wrote this script:

```
import re

arrayofhex =[]
hexedarr=[]
string_input = raw_input()
key = "0x3c"
encodehex = string_input.encode("hex")

hexsplit = re.findall('..?', encodehex)


for letter in hexsplit:
     a = hex(int(letter,16))
     arrayofhex.append(a)

print arrayofhex

print "Xoring with Key 0x3c turns to:"

for hexedletter in arrayofhex:

    xor = hex(int(hexedletter,16) ^ int(key,16))
    hexedarr.append(xor)

print hexedarr
```

As you can see the user can insert some string and then the code makes it a hex and xor it with a key which is 0x3c, i want to get the ascii of the xoring process can someone help?

Comment: `chr( your hex value ) `?

Comment: Your program is supposed to convert a character to ascii, xor it with `0x3c` and then convert it back to a character, right? Then, this is it: `chr(ord(character) ^ 0x3c)`

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, you should definitely target Python 3 now.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i made some changes and got it to work here is the full script which works great!!

```
import re

Array_of_hex =[]
Hexed_array=[]
Xord_array=[]

string_input = raw_input()
key = "0x3c"

Encode_to_hex = string_input.encode("hex")

Hex_split = re.findall('..?', Encode_to_hex)


for letter in Hex_split:
     a = hex(int(letter,16))
     Array_of_hex.append(a)

print Array_of_hex

print "Xoring with Key 0x3c turns to:"

for hexedletter in Array_of_hex:

    xor = hex(int(hexedletter,16) ^ int(key,16))
    Hexed_array.append(xor)

print Hexed_array


for hextoascii_letter in Hexed_array:
    toascii = chr(int(hextoascii_letter,16))
    Xord_array.append(toascii)


xord_string = "".join(Xord_array)
print "Xored Ascii:"
print xord_string
```